# JSX Conditional Rendering for Nested Object Values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, jsx

I am attempting to have a "flashcard" show no background color when it is unanswered, green when it is correctly answered, and yellow when it is incorrectly answered. The properties for each card are stored in a nested object. I am having issues using conditional rendering to properly show my content.

**Code:** Here is what I want to accomplish, but the JSX conditional statement is only registering the last statement in the className.

```
<div className="row">
    {Object.keys(this.state.selections).map( (lang, index) => (
        <>
            {Object.keys(this.state.selections[lang]).map( (cat, index) => (
                <>
                {Object.keys(this.state.selections[lang][cat]).map( (sect, index)=> (
                    <>
                    {Object.keys(this.state.selections[lang][cat][sect]).map( (letter, index)=> (
                        <>
                        {this.state.selections[lang][cat][sect][letter].show &&
                            <div className={
                                (this.state.selections[lang][cat][sect][letter].correct ? correct: unanswered),
                                (this.state.selections[lang][cat][sect][letter].incorrect ? incorrect : unanswered)
                            } key= {index}>
                            </div>
                        }
                        </>
                    ))}
                    </>
                ))}
                </>
            ))}
        </>
    ))}
</div>
```

Essentially, I want to place a conditional statement in the className to change the background based off the object property values being true/false.

**Obj model:**

```
{
    "Hiragana": {
        "Main Kana": {
            "Vowels": {
                "a": {
                    "characterName":  "A",
                    "character":  "あ",
                    "unicode":  "\u0026‌#12354;",
                    "hexEncoding":  "\u0026‌#x3042",
                    "englishTranslation":  "a",
                    "alternateEnglishTranslation":  "",
                    "isLetter":  "1",
                    "alphabet":  "hir",
                    "show": false,
                    "answer": "",
                    "correct": false,
                    "incorrect": false,
                    "unanswered": true
                    },
```

**Bonus question:** Having to loop through each object layer seems a bit messy and tedious... Would there be any good way to shorten this up? The **lang** and **cat** are selected by input so they cannot be hard-coded. While my current solution "works" I want to improve myself when possible.

**Update:** Working code from the solution offered by @CertainPerformance

```
<div className="row">
    {Object.keys(this.state.selections).map(lang => 
        Object.values(this.state.selections).map( (cat) =>
            Object.values(cat).map((sect, indexCat) =>
                Object.values(sect).map((sectLetters, indexSect) =>
                    Object.values(sectLetters).map((letter, indexSectL) =>
                        letter.show &&
                        <div
                            className={getBgClass(letter)}
                            key={indexSectL}>
                            <div>
                                <h5 className="card-title" >{letter.character}</h5>
                                <input data-lang={lang} data-cat={Object.getOwnPropertyNames(cat)[indexCat]} data-sect={Object.getOwnPropertyNames(sect)[indexSect]} type="text" name={letter.characterName} value={letter.answer} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )}
</div>
```

For those confused by my explanation of accessing the array generated by Object.values, here is an example with simple console.log to better explain.

```
Object.values(this.state.selections).map((cat) =>{
    Object.values(cat).map((sect, indexCat) => {
        console.log("Cat: ", Object.getOwnPropertyNames(cat)[indexCat]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if your current code works as you're expecting it to. Here:

```
className={
  (this.state.selections[lang][cat][sect][letter].correct ? correct : unanswered),
  (this.state.selections[lang][cat][sect][letter].incorrect ? incorrect : unanswered)
}
```

you're invoking the comma operator, which evaluates to only the final expression in the comma-separated list. It's equivalent to:

```
className={
  (this.state.selections[lang][cat][sect][letter].incorrect ? incorrect : unanswered)
}
```

To fix it, either use a nested conditional operator, or pass it into a function.

To make your code more concise, instead of iterating over the *keys* of the object, iterate over the *values* of the object. You also don't need a fragment `<></>` when returning an array.

```
<div className="row">
    {Object.values(this.state.selections).map(selection =>
        Object.values(selection).map(cat =>
            Object.values(cat).map(sect =>
                Object.values(sect).map((letter, index) =>
                    letter.show &&
                    <div
                        className={
                            letter.correct
                                ? correct
                                : letter.incorrect
                                    ? incorrect
                                    :
                                    unanswered
                        }
                        key={index}
                    >
                    </div>
                )
            )
        )
    )}
</div>
```

To avoid the nested conditional, if that's your preference, do something like:

```
<div
    className={getClass(letter)}
    key={index}
></div>
```

```
const getClass = (letter) => {
  if (letter.correct) return correct;
  if (letter.incorrect) return incorrect;
  return unanswered;
};
```

You could also consider changing your model so that the question state (correct/incorrect/unanswered) is a single property, rather than multiple, eg, instead of

```
"correct": false,
"incorrect": false,
"unanswered": true
```

have

```
answerState: 2
```

where 2 corresponds to unanswered, 1 corresponds to incorrect, and 0 corresponds to correct - or something like that. Then you can use an array to look up the appropriate class name:

```
className={classNames[letter.answerState]}
```

```
const classNames = [correct, incorrect, unanswered];
```

Comment: You are a blessed individual. This is everything I needed and more. I think I am going to keep the three properties for now so I can better visualize it. Also figuring out how to drill into Object.values is very interesting... It seems that in order for you to access the array it generates you have to next another .map function and use the nested's index to loop through the parent... Very strange and hard to explain, but I will update my question with the final result!